# RestSharp POST not returning anything from Azure environment, but does locally

Tags: azure, api, post, restsharp

I've made this type of call dozens of times, but for some reason this isn't working in my testing environment in Azure, but works on my localhost just fine. The result never returns from my service, not even a timeout error or "0" response, nothing. What could I be missing when calling an api endpoint? No errors in my logs either.

The only way I'm able to get a response is if I **remove** the Timeout = 2700000, which in that case it returns "0" response. But my call is taking more than a few minutes, so without the Timeout set, it will always return a "0" response.

UPDATE: I've also tried using await/async calls, no luck either. 
UPDATE: I switched from restsharp and used a Httpclient call instead, and still same results. So I don't even think its a restsharp issue alone.

```
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            var restClient = new RestClient(appSettings["Url"]);

            var request = new RestRequest("api/Sync")
            {
                Method = Method.POST,
                Timeout = 2700000,
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            };
            request.AddHeader("authUser", appSettings["username"]);
            request.AddHeader("authPass", appSettings["password"]);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializeItem);
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var result = restClient.Execute(request);

            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObj>(result.Content);
```

Comment: this issue I'm having might be related to Azure Load Balancer timing out at 4 minutes, still investigating. I have a call that did go through within 4 minutes, but my next call which takes 7 fails to return a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to fix this issue, I had to put: 
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 180000, 60000);

The connection between my web job and service was timing out due to idle inactivity.